# Use another MacBook as extended display via Thunderbolt 2 cable?

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt-display

I am currently using a MacBook Pro 2015 with Iris Pro 2G graphic card, which supports up to 2 extended display (I tried to setup 3 extended monitor - 2x Thunderbolt 2 + 1x HDMI, it won't work, 1 screen has to go dark). On the other hand I also have a MacBook Pro 2013 with a broken screen. Both MBPs have 2x Thunderbolt port and 1x HDMI.

MBP 2015 has a 3-screen setup:

1. Laptop screen
2. Thunderbolt 2 to DVI on FHD monitor (extended)
3. HDMI to DVI on FHD monitor (extended)

MBP 2013 has a single screen setup:

1. Laptop screen - broken
2. Thunderbolt 2 to DVI on FHD monitor (mirror, not extended)

My question is,

1. Is it possible to use a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 2 cable connect these 2 MBP and make the 2013 MBP's FHD monitor as another extended display to make MBP 2015 to total of 4 screens?
2. If not, any suggestion to make the most of the MBP 2013?

Comment: To make the most of the 2013 MBP, [replace the screen](http://amzn.to/2EIfDsu).  It's a good laptop with tons of life left in it.  It's not a too difficult fix to replace it.  See [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Display+Assembly+Replacement/27666) for instructions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Allan. I had look at the tread that you guys suggested, I wasn't quite sure, is the answer to my question is a NO because the only supported devices are iMac?

Answer (score 0):

[ScreenRecycler](https://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html) enables you to use your MBP 2013 as an additional display for your MBP 2015 laptop. It's not very expensive (about $30).

Both computers need to be connected together through the local network (can be either Ethernet or WiFi, or maybe even a Thunderbolt Cable if you really want that).

The MBP 2013 needs to be running Mac OS X 10.8, 10.9, or 10.10 (because ScreenRecycler is not compatible with 10.11 and newer).

Comment: This is not a good solution because 1) Thunderbolt is a PCIe bus - you just can't jam them together (as you say) *if you want* and 2) 10.8 through 10.10 are *deprecated* operating system.  They are no longer being updated and are obsolete.

Comment: You're wrong : it's possible (and very easy) to make a network connection between two macs over a standard Thunderbolt cable. See : https://9to5mac.com/2016/11/22/macbook-pro-thunderbolt-3-bridge-network-video/